# Internal working of 'use strict' in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, ecmascript-5

In spite of the use of use strict i want know **how use strict works internally**. 
who controls the behavior of the use strict? Is it a browser or JavaScript framework who takes care of Strict mode?

Comment: _"Is it a browser or JavaScript framework who takes care of Strict mode?"_ - How could it be anything other than the browser? `"use strict"` changes the way certain fundamental parts of the language work, so...

Comment: @nnnnnn This may be obvious to you an I, but if it was obvious to the person asking, they wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: You'll find the [MDN entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) informative. There's also some info in the [ECMAScript 5 spec](http://es5.github.io/#C).

Comment: @Brad - I was hoping to prompt the OP to think it through. Also, there are any number of articles about strict mode - surely reading a couple of those and not seeing "You will need framework X to use strict mode" mentioned is a clue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JavaScript/ECMAScript engine within the browser itself is what takes care of interpreting this directive.  This is a feature of ECMAScript 5.